# Fieldable Panels Panes: title is shown twice

Tags: display-suite

When putting fieldable panel panes on a (panel) page the titel field is shown twice. It makes nog difference whether I choose a Display Suite or Panels layout. How can I change this?

I don't know if this is related but I can't figure out how to config a DS view mode, once I've created it and attributed it to 'fieldable panels panes'.

[image]